# "You should only X or Y" vs "You should only X and Y."

Tags: word-choice, conjunctions

Example sentence:

> You should only ask them questions about movies and cartoons.
>
> You should only ask them questions about movies or cartoons.

Do the two sentences imply pretty much the same? Or they entail different meanings?

I know, one if using "and" and the other is using "or." But to me, both sentences read like: "movies and/or cartoons are the only topics that you are allowed to ask."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written those are pretty much the same, and probably both would be heard.

The first *might* be understood as "only questions about cartoon-movies, not about live-action movies, or tv cartoons". The second *might* be understood as "only question about movies, or question about cartoons, but not a mix". However, I think these interpretations are unlikely.

A similar problem arises when a maths student wants to express "the values x>3 and values x<1" and prompted the development of the union and intersection notation to avoid ambiguity.